# Add warning messages to ILineBreakpoint in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I wrote custom remote debugger for a specific environment. However, the remote environment performs several optimizations that move or delete pieces of original code and therefore it can't accept all breakpoints. Before debugger session starts and connects to the remote runtime, we can't predict which of the breakpoints can't be set. I would like to keep these breakpoints as they are set in editor, but when the debugger starts, it must somehow tell the user that certain breakpoints are invalid. I think that these breakpoints should look different way, but I haven't found API methods for this purpose. I tried to set IMarker attributes such as IMarker.PROBLEM and IMarker.SEVERITY, but it didn't help. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution by myself, but it looks like a dirty hack. It works only with `IJavaLineBreakpoint`, for another languages another solution required, but for now Java support is enough. `IJavaLineBreakpoint` had the `isInstalled` method that indicates whether the breakpoint is installed into some JVM. Unfortunately, you have no direct way to modity this flag. Internal implementation just exposes value of the `org.eclipse.jdt.debug.core.installCount` attribute. So, to set *installed* property of a breakpoint, you should do the following:

```
breakpoint.getMarker().setAttribute("org.eclipse.jdt.debug.core.installCount", 1);
```

Also, you can just increase/decrease this attribute the same way. However, I am not sure that this approach is compatible across versions of JDT.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet from the Eclipse Debugger guide is probably what you are looking for:

```
public PDALineBreakpoint(IResource resource, int lineNumber) throws CoreException {
     IMarker marker = resource.createMarker(
         "org.eclipse.debug.examples.core.pda.lineBreakpoint.marker");
     setMarker(marker);
     setEnabled(true);
     ensureMarker().setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, lineNumber);
     ensureMarker().setAttribute(IBreakpoint.ID, IPDAConstants.ID_PDA_DEBUG_MODEL);
}
```

https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Debugger/how-to.html

Comment: The problem is that I don't declare my own breakpoint class. I use the existing one instead. In fact, it is a `IJavaLineBreakpoint`. I would like to be compatible with different languages and not depend on a certain breakpoint class. But for first time coupling with JDT would be accepted to create a proof of concept for Java.